# How can I create this shape in Visio?

Tags: microsoft-visio, flowchart

I want to create a shape like this, with 3 rows that I can hold text:

[image: Table]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried going through all the shape categories. I only see shapes with 2 rows, but not 3.

Comment: [Create, save, and share custom stencils](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-save-and-share-custom-stencils-a4c2235c-677d-4117-9673-1fef0a0ee22f)

Comment: [Edit a master shape](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/edit-a-master-shape-8b74915c-6ae4-4051-89f2-c1972bd62c87)

Comment: Item 4 in https://www.paulherber.co.uk/free-visio-shapes/